# Does severity of covid vaccine side effects correlate with or suggest anything about how badly that person would have reacted to covid itself?

Tags: covid-19

Let's say that a person has the covid vaccine and has a relatively bad case of the standard side effects. Does their reaction to the vaccine suggest that they would have also felt very poorly on the virus itself?

My loose and uninformed thinking is that the symptoms are related to the immune system working, and therefore maybe would have occurred in both cases. This is presumably untestable, but if we have a good understanding of what causes the symptoms in both cases, perhaps we can say that they both occur under similar conditions in the body.

Comment: How could one test this counterfactual?

Comment: @Fizz I wouldn't expect one to be able to test it, but perhaps knowledge about the mechanisms would be able to lead one towards an answer.